# Can't access Chorus Pro API in Postman

Tags: api, request, postman

I'm working on a custom module for Odoo 15, but I'm currently facing an issue with the Chorus Pro API.

Everything about authentication and API key generation looks ok on their website.

But when I try some requests in Postman it always returns me "400 Bad Request" and I don't understand why.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

***Update 1***

Ok so after several tests it return me "Unable to find token in the message".

But I specified it in the Authorization menu with type API Key.

Here the official documentation: https://developer.aife.economie.gouv.fr/index.php?option=com_apiportal&view=apitester&usage=api&apitab=tests&apiName=Factures&apiId=5feff6ae-09cd-46a6-a0b9-844eac6b9acc&managerId=2&type=rest&apiVersion=1.0.0&Itemid=265&swaggerVersion=2.0&lang=fr

(Sorry it's in french)

***Update 2***

I finally get an API Key and change the Authorization Type to Bearer Token so the previous error is solved.

But now I've got "403 Forbidden" because of an "[invalid field]".

I use this POST URL : https://sandbox-api.piste.gouv.fr/cpro/factures/v1/corriger/valideur/facture

With this body :

> {   "idFacture": 0,   "idStructure": 0,   "typeIdentifiantStructure":
> "SIRET",   "identifiantStructure": "string" }

***Update 3***

The "[invalid field]" seems to be the host one, but it's the same as in  the POST URL : sandbox-api.piste.gouv.fr

Comment: Without seeing examples, links to documentations the community won't be able to help. Alas, 400 is not an auth issue, so your problem so far is with the request body/params.

Comment: In this case, 400 is an auth issue. This API is the worse I ever met, both in term of documentation and HTTP protocol usage.

@quentin-villanova, I'm facing the same issue. Did you found an answer ? Could you describe the requests fields you needed to pass the authentication ?

Comment: Hi, I talk with the customer support for 3 days now, I'll be back when my issue is solve ;)
For now, I can only say that you need to edit your application on PISTE and check the API you want to use at the bottom of the page.
I'm currently facing an error 500.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Hi, i'm trying to use the Chorus API also. Did you manage to get it works ? If yes, can we reach us by email or other ? (i'm french)

Comment: @Nathan30 I indeed did. In the Chorus Pro world, an HTTP 403 is used when user input validation failed.
I can't quite remember the exact issue I had. I can share the working chorus pro access code if it can help. I'm not sure I can share this publicly. If this seems fine to you, just give me a way to contact you.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Can you add me on Linkedin ? https://www.linkedin.com/in/nathan-cheval